Difference between average predictions and interactions in marginal effects
I  have a fixed efffects model where I am interested in  the marginal effects of a categorical variable across time. The following is  an example indicating what I am doing:
# Load necessary packages
library(fixest)
library(marginaleffects)
library(ggplot2)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Number of observations
n <- 500  # 10 time points, 50 observations each

# Simulate the data
data <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:n,
  Time = factor(rep(1:10, each = 50)),  
  # 10 time points, 50 observations each
  Category = factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), length.out = n)),  
  # 3-level categorical independent variable
  Control1 = rnorm(n, mean = 50, sd = 10),  
  # Continuous control variable with some variation
  Control2 = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE)  
  # Binary control variable with random assignment
)

# Binary outcome variable, designed to vary with Category and Time

data$Outcome <- rbinom(n, 1, 
    prob = plogis(0.5 + 0.3 * as.numeric(data$Category) - 
                  0.2 * as.numeric(data$Time) + 0.05 * data$Control1 - 
                  0.1 * data$Control2))

# Fit the model with fixed effects
model <- feglm(
  Outcome ~ Category + Control1 + Control2 | Time,
  data = data,
  family = binomial("logit")
)

# Summary of the model
summary(model)

# Get average predictions by Category and Time
predictions <- avg_predictions(model, by = c("Category", "Time"))

# Display the predictions
print(predictions)

# Plot the predictions with confidence intervals
ggplot(predictions, aes(x = Time, y = estimate, color = Category, 
                        group = Category)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, fill = Category),
              alpha = 0.2, color = NA) +
  labs(title = "Predicted Probabilities by Category over Time",
       x = "Time",
       y = "Predicted Probability") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))

I have two questions:

What is the difference between plotting marginal effects of Category variables across values of the Time variable versus interacting each time variable with each category and plotting the marginal effects of those interactions?  I understand that including interaction would assume that the effect might be moderated by time, but would a marginal effects approach not show the same thing if the data dictates so? So for instance, if time = 3 category A has a significantly higher likelihood of the outcome than the baseline, this might be reflected in data, even without the interaction terms, right?
With or without adding the interaction term   (Category*Time), what would be the right approach to analyze the conditional effect of time per category gradually? For instance, if I want to identify the values for Time = 3, Category A, Time = 4, Category = A, Time = 5, Category, in terms of  change in the estimated compared to the previous time


What do you mean by "each wave with each category"?  What do you mean by "Wave" here?

Sorry, I meant to say Time. given that time is a factor variable interaction of each time value with each level in the category. @DemetriPananos

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is it better now? @Community
